# Examples of inite regular rings that are not semi-simple rings

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a ring with unit.  An element $a$ is called  (von Neumann) regular if there exists an element $x\in R$ such that $a=axa$.  A ring is called regular if every element of $R$ is regular.   I know that finite regular rings are unit regular, that is, for each $a\in R$ there exists a unit $u\in R$ such that $a=aua$.

My question is:  Are there examples of finite regular rings that are not semi-simple rings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because a Noetherian (and of course that includes Artinian and finite) von Neumann regular ring is already semisimple.

One way to see:  von Neumann regular means the finitely generated right ideals are summands.  Noetherian+VNR means all right ideals are summands.